# Downloading file from server stops after 2 minutes

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Some of our users are having problems downloading .pdf files from our site. When the file takes more than ~2 minutes to download, it suddenly stops, causing the downloaded file to be unopenable. This is a huge problem for users on slow connections who are trying to download large documents.

We are using a slightly modified version of [this](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/08/downloading-any-file-using-asp-fso-and-the-adodb-stream-object/) asp code to handle the downloads. The browser will automatically download other file types like .zip, but this script is used to download .pdfs so they don't just open in the browser.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure it's a timeout issue and not a request size one?

Comment: Yep, works fine on faster connections. And when I tried to throttle network speeds on the faster computer from chrome's device mode, it failed after 2 minutes again.

Comment: What's the value of `Server.ScriptTimeout`?

Comment: Also, have you tried chunking it?

Comment: Ah, the Server.ScriptTimeout seems to have been the problem. It was still set to the default. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer for others who find this post and are having similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of `Server.ScriptTimeout` is 90 (seconds). If you find that your downloads are interrupted after a minute or two, try increasing the value of this property.

```
<%
    ' Bump the default timeout from 90 seconds to 5 minutes...
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 300
%>
```